# Rfacebook Packages getpage() command only retrieving a few posts from Facebook Pages

Tags: r, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I recently tried Rfacebook package by pablobarbera, which works quite well. I am having this slight issue, for which I am sharing the code.

```
install.packages("Rfacebook")  # from CRAN
library(devtools)
install_github("Rfacebook", "pablobarbera", subdir = "Rfacebook")

library(Rfacebook)
# token generated here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer 
token <- "**********"

page <- getPage("DarazOnlineShopping", token, n = 1000)
```

`getPage` command works, but it only retrieves 14 records from the Facebook page I used in the command. In the example used by pablobarbera in the original post he retreived all the posts from "Humans of New York", but when I tried the same command, facebook asked me to reduce the number of posts, and I hardly managed to get 20 posts. This  is the command used by Pablo bera:

```
page <- getPage("humansofnewyork", token, n = 5000)
```

I thought I was using temporary token access that why Facebook is not giving me the required data, but I completed the wholo Facebook Oauth Process, and the same result.

Can somebody look into this, and tell why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The getPage() command looks fine to me, I manually counted 14 posts (including photos) on the main page. It could be that Daraz Online Shopping has multiple pages and that the page name you are using only returns results from the main page, when (I assume) you want results from all of them.

getPage() also accepts page IDs. You might want to collect a list of IDs associated with Daraz Online Shopping, loop through and call each of them and combine the outputs to get the results you need.

To find this out these IDs you could write a scraper (or manually search for them all) that views the page source and searches for the unique page ID. Searching for `content="fb://page/?id=` will highlight the location of the page ID in the source code.